# When I split a task, where can I find the dates related to the cut?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

When I split a task, where can I find the dates related to the cut ?

I mean:

- Start date;
- End and start of the first cut;
- Start of the second cut;
- End of the second part of the task.

Comment: Is the split created by actual work being logged and then rescheduled? Or did you just split the task?

Comment: normally, it is a situation where I send a letter to a firm to ask here to STOP WORKING for a while, so the solution for now is to *split* using the split button.

Comment: If the company has accomplished work (actual work) the progress should be tracked.  If you then need to stop the work and reschedule - I would not create a split using the split task command.  Record the Actual Work (or Actual duration) - then use the "Reschedule uncompleted work" command in Update Project.  If you do that, you will see the date the work halted in the "Stop" field and the date the work is scheduled to begin again in the "Resume" field.

Comment: interesting ... can you propose it as an Answer and please details the difference between *duration* and *actual duration* so that I upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover over the section with the mouse and the section start and end dates will be shown onscreen.

Comment: you are right. that's one way to do that. But there is no *custom fields* for those informations ? I can't split a task with a mouse , I need to type dates, if you know what I mean.

Comment: If you literally need to treat each section as a separate task in its own right, with start and end dates, then you *are* talking about different tasks, not different chunks of work within a task. There might be some way to access the information you want, though it's beyond me, but it sounds like you want separate tasks...

Answer (score 0):

If the company has accomplished work (actual work) the progress should be tracked. If you then need to stop the work and reschedule - I would not create a split using the split task command. Record the Actual Work (or Actual duration) - then use the "Reschedule uncompleted work" command in Update Project. If you do that, you will see the date the work halted in the "Stop" field and the date the work is scheduled to begin again in the "Resume" field.

The difference between Duration and Actual duration is that "actuals" are used in tracking.  The process *should be* as follows:

Create the schedule:

- Set the working calendar and options
- Add tasks entering estimated duration
- Create a logical relationship (predecessors, successors)
- Create resources
- Assign resources to tasks

Once the schedule is agreed upon - save a baseline.

Once work starts, you need to start tracking the progress on the project.  By entering % complete - Project will calculate actual duration and will also calculate remaining duration.  (Take a look at the tracking table).  If there is more time needed - adjust the remaining duration and the % complete will be recalculated.  Or - better yet - enter actual duration and remaining to calculate % complete from the beginning.

When you use the "Reschedule" command - remaining duration (and work) is rescheduled to resume on the new start date.  It also splits the task.