# How to add special, non-continuous dates to one task?

Tags: ms-project-2013

I am using Microsoft Project Standard 2013 and would like to know how I can add a split task to my gantt diagram.

This task shell visualize dates where no changes to our infrastructure are allowed. Therefor this task has more than one beginning and ending. E.g:

- Task 1: 1th of June to 31th of August
- Task 2: 1th of July to 31th of August
- Frozen Zone: 1th of August to 4th August **and** 29th of August to 31th of August

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You're looking for a way to impose task constraints/work authorization system to tasks in project.

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/when-i-split-a-task-where-can-i-find-the-dates-related-to-the-cut/15526#15526

Answer (score 1):

Just add a task first, and then split it later.

Or, follow as here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-a-task-20c8581b-6266-45e3-af54-cc7c3b10deca

The special frozen zone that you describe is very close to the example used therein.

As another option, you can also simply reschedule the remainder of the task as described here:
http://www.brighthubpm.com/software-reviews-tips/4973-project-2007-rescheduling-tasks-and-incomplete-work/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but it seems to me that you could add a resource to the mix  - call it "Authorization" - During 6/11/ to 8/31 "Authorization is 100% occupied on the task "Configuration freeze" and unable to work on the task.

That should prevent any work from occurring on that task during that period.

Alternatively, I believe that project permits you to identify custom calendars - you should be able to create a custom calendar listing the freeze periods as non-working holidays.